The makefile rules are not working properly
code:
CC = gcc
RM = rm
OBJ = target
OBJS = test.o sqlist.o
BUILD_DIR = build

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(OBJ): $(BUILD_DIR)/$(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^

$(BUILD_DIR)/test.o: test.c
    $(CC) -c $^ -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/sqlist.o: sqlist.c
    $(CC) -c $^ -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*

.PHONY: clean

my problem is: The makefile file did not generate sqlist.o in the build directory but instead created it in the makefile directory.

GNU Make 4.3


Please [edit] your question to show the full and complete output from running make.

This rule:
$(BUILD_DIR)/$(OBJ): $(BUILD_DIR)/$(OBJS)

expands to:
build/target: build/test.o sqlist.o

So Make is quite right to build sqlist.o in the working directory, using the built-in rule.

So it should be $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(OBJS)).
